# Insert string into a specified location of a 2D vector

Tags: c++, vector

so all im trying to do is insert a string into my vector

```
class World
{
    public:
        void writeCell(int writelocW, int writelocH, std::string input);
    private:
        std::vector<std::string> wH;
    std::vector< std::vector<std::string> > grid;
};

void World::writeCell(int writelocW, int writelocH, std::string input)
{
   wH.insert(wH.begin()+writelocH,1,input);
   grid.insert(grid.begin()+writelocW,1,wH);
}
```

with the parameters of `writeCell` being read from another header.

but the file gives me an error `"vector iterator + offset out of range"` when i run it
with `writelocW` and `writelocH` both set to 1 and input to `"Desc"`. the error seems to be called by the `"+writelocH"` part of `wH.insert`. How can i fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check vector size before insert into random position. If vector size is smaller than `writelocH` you get 'out of range' exception:

replace

```
wH.insert(wH.begin()+writelocH,1,input);
grid.insert(grid.begin()+writelocW,1,wH);
```

with:

```
if (wH.size() > writelocH)
{
   wH.insert(wH.begin() + writelocH,1,input);
   grid.insert(grid.begin()+writelocW,1,wH);
}
else
{
   wH.insert(wH.begin(),1,input);    
   grid.insert(grid.begin(),1,wH);
 }
```

Comment: aargh i've been so blind, i thought it might be a problem of "writelocH" being an integer but that.... thank you so much!